# How to create from console Wear OS emulator with google play?

Tags: android-emulator, wear-os

It's rather easy to create wear emulator with google play from Android Studoio AVD manager, but I want to create it from console.
When I try

```
./cmdline-tools/latest/bin/avdmanager create avd \
    --force \
    --name "wear_test" \
    --package "system-images;android-28;android-wear;x86" \
    --abi x86 \
    --tag "android-wear" \
    --device "wear_round_chin_360_325"
```

the result emulator does not have play store, but creating emulator with the same system image from android studio contains it.

Comment: It looks like it has the playstore anyway, is it missing for you from the app menu?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/203751423